# Image to the left, text centered (in page)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an about me page, where i would like an image to the left of the container and the text to the right aligned centered to the page.
this is what i've got

```
<img link img>
<h2>
jack
</h2>
<p>
dummy text
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0sozwjk/1/

```css
article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}

.dark {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <Section id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <article id="main-About-Col">
        <h1 class="PTitle">About us</h1>
        <div class="dark">
          <img style="float:left; vertical-align:center;" alt="Jack Picture" width="125px" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1000172/291874463/stock-vector-notebook-template-vector-example-of-using-hand-drawn-food-pattern-for-cover-of-cooking-book-291874463.jpg">
          <h2>
            Jack
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
            sem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </Section>
</center>
```

Comment: Your fiddle looks like the description you are giving. What different do you exactly want from your example?

Comment: try this one https://jsfiddle.net/a0sozwjk/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display flex` to make image as vertical center

https://jsfiddle.net/a0sozwjk/4/

```css
article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}

.dark {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 250px;
}

.dark .imagediv{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <Section id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <article id="main-About-Col">
        <h1 class="PTitle">About us</h1>
        <div class="dark">
          <div class="imagediv">
          <img style="float:left; vertical-align:center;" alt="Jack Picture" width="125px" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1000172/291874463/stock-vector-notebook-template-vector-example-of-using-hand-drawn-food-pattern-for-cover-of-cooking-book-291874463.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>
          Jack
         </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
            sem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </Section>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put the elements in a flexbox, group the text elements in the same flex child, then use `align-items: center;`!

Does it work for you?

```css
article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}

.dark {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <Section id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <article id="main-About-Col">
        <h1 class="PTitle">About us</h1>
        <div class="dark">
          <img style="float:left; vertical-align:center;" alt="Jack Picture" width="125px" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1000172/291874463/stock-vector-notebook-template-vector-example-of-using-hand-drawn-food-pattern-for-cover-of-cooking-book-291874463.jpg">
          <div>
          <h2>
            Jack
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
            sem.
          </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </Section>
</center>
```

Here is a cheatsheet if you don't know about flexboxes yet: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the text in a div and add `overflow: hidden;` like this https://jsfiddle.net/a0sozwjk/2/